# How to add a second condition to my existing SQL STATEMENT?

Tags: mysql, subquery

So the question asks me about displaying the name, population, continent, independence year and life expectancy of the countries whose Independence year is AAA, or who are neither in Asia nor in Europe.

> SELECT Name, Population, Continent, IndepYear, LifeExpectancy FROM
>   country
>
> WHERE (IndepYear = 'AAA'  AND Continent IN ('Asia' , 'Europe')) OR  IndepYear = 'AAA' ;

[image][image]

I've tried pretty much everything but couldn't get that one. Any pointer will be more than appreciated

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

I read the question as follows:

```
SELECT Name
     , Population
     , Continent
     , IndepYear
     , LifeExpectancy 
  FROM country 
 WHERE IndepYear = 'AAA' 
   AND Continent NOT IN ('Asia' , 'Europe');
```

Comment: I tried that and the QUERY INFO LOG says query returned no results!

Comment: Indepyear with 'AAA' excluding Asia and Europe (but INCLUDING IndepYear with 'AAA' in Asia and Europe) Is what I need. I do not know how to write the but and I tried the "WITH" with no luck.
I am actually looking in joining two types of results, one being anything with NULL and take out any Asian or  European  country without NULL

Comment: You're not making much sense

Comment: I am sorry. I wish I could explain it better but this what I have. Thank you for trying to help though !

Answer (score 0):

Continent is not tied to independence year in the question and in is shorthand for or you want the opposite

```
SELECT Name, Population, Continent, IndepYear, LifeExpectancy 
FROM country
WHERE (Continent <> 'Asia' and continent <> 'Europe') OR IndepYear = 'AAA' ;
```

Comment: I have tried that before in the opposite manner and it gave me the same error as your code; An error saying that I missed the European and Asian country with IndepYear = 'AAA'

Comment: Then the question is wrong/ambiguous - did you print the exact question? Can you add sample data and expected output to the question. AND this code won't throw an error so where did the error come from?

Comment: I feel like the homework is either broken or the phrasing is wrong as I have tried to write this as a response  to the error: WHERE ((Continent = 'Asia' and continent = 'Europe') AND IndepYear = 'AAA')  OR IndepYear = 'AAA' ; but gt no luck and I have been trying for close to 4 hours now

Comment: Yes I did, In the homework software it says exactly: Display the name, population, continent, independence year and life expectancy of the countries whose Independence year is NULL, or who are neither in Asia nor in Europe

Comment: Continent = 'Asia' and continent = 'Europe - can never be true and 'AAA' is not the same as NULL

Comment: I did not want to copy-paste the whole question that is why I wrote AAA. What do you mean by they can never be true? I think that is what I'm probably missing.. I think the response is any country with 'NULL' as IndepYear but not any European or Asian Country without 'NULL' as IndepYear. I'm failing to do that :(

Comment: A continent cannot be  both asia and europe it's one of them

Comment: I guess this is also wrong?
 "WHERE (((Continent = 'Asia' OR continent = 'Europe') AND IndepYear = 'NULL') OR IndepYear = 'NULL' ;"

Comment: Yes - null is never = to anything it's either IS NULL or IS NOT NULL

Comment: WHERE IndepYear = 'NULL' OR Continent NOT IN Continent ('Asia', 'Europe'); This query gives me the right answer short of 7 rows which are in Europe and Asia with IndepYear 'NULL'

Comment: Null and 'null' are not the same the first indicates no value exists the second is a string (which is possible to test with =). Can you add sample data and table definition as text to the question.

Comment: I just added what  I see from the software. The screenshot of my screen shows you the result of this query WHERE IndepYear = 'NULL' OR Continent NOT IN Continent ('Asia', 'Europe') I know 'null' and 'NULL' are different and that is why I wanted to use AAA to clear this confusion. Thank you for trying to help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Give this a try

Its working for me with all Indepyear with 'AAA' excluding Asia and Europe

SELECT `Name`, `Population`, `Continent`, `IndepYear`, `LifeExpectancy`
FROM `country`
WHERE `IndepYear` = 'AAA' OR `Continent` NOT IN ('Asia' , 'Europe');

Comment: Indepyear with 'AAA' excluding Asia and Europe (but INCLUDING IndepYear with 'AAA' in Asia and Europe) Is what I need